# Why does my g3xn sound off?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, audio-feedback

I recently bought an audio interface. It's a Behringer UMC 22 and a Behringer HPS 3000 headphone monitor and I have been using the same patches of a YouTuber called “Direct Recording Guitar” and for some reason all my patches don't sound as bright as was demonstrated.

Does it have to do with the cable or the audio interface that I use? I plug it in as guitar + zoom g3xn + Behringer UMC 22 + laptop. Did plug it in wrong somehow?

Comment: We don't know what you need or what you can hear, nor any difference between the two. As it stands this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Your signal chain looks right. Try some basic troubleshooting. I would suggest plugging in your headphones at all the different stages of the signal and see if you can figure out at which stage the sound changes. Start at the Zoom. If it doesn’t sound bright there it could be the sound of your guitar (the instrument itself, pickups, strings, tone controls) or you could have a pair of headphones that are very dark sounding. Experiment at that stage (different phones, new strings,  another guitar, etc.). It could also be the settings on the Zoom itself.

If you like the sound there then move on and listen through the UMC22 then the headphone amp. You can also try the different stages through your monitor speakers. Wherever you hear a change in the sound will give you an idea of where the problem lies.